# updating resources automatically on each build?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm building this iPhone app that has a set of resources that I, during development, update a lot. These resources are later used by my app.

The thing is, whenever I make a change in these resources and do a regular build, the resources aren't actually updated within my iphone application. In fact, they are never updated until I clean the build and rebuild the entire application after which all is fine.

Is there a way to make xcode always include my resources in each build?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the resources to your application wrapper by using a copy files build phase in your target, Xcode usually does the right thing. Xcode decides wether or not to copy a file based on it's modification date.

Check if the modification dates of your original files and copies in the app wrapper match and if, after updating the resources, the modification dates of the updated files are newer than those in the app wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I am (now) copying the resources (might be the wrong term, I'm copying some directories containing images and a config.plist, they're copied into the Resources directory though) using a copy-files build phase.

Xcode still doesn't update them unless I clean the build first.

Comment: Dependency tracking on contents of copied directories does not work. File a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: It appears that with Xcode 3.2.2 (provided with iPhone SDK 3.2) the issue is solved.